# How to use a JavaScript file that needs another JavaScript file (incl. modules) on the frontend of my node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa

Currently, I am working on a smart home system at home, but my frontend won't work properly. What should happen: Frontend sends RSA-Encrypted data to my apache2 server, which runs also node.js. Then the server should decrypt the data and execute the proper function of the request so that the frontend receives a proper response (the server works as intended, I tested it with a program called "Insomnia" which can generate any kind of request, in my case there are POST-Request which contains JSON-Objects in the body section).

Below you will find an example of my project.

**Frontend**
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  <title>Smart Home</title>
</head>
<body>
...
<button id="btn1" class="numPad-btn">btn1</button>
...
</body>
<script type="module" src="connection.js"></script>
</html>
```

**connectio.js**

```
import * as _crypto from './Crypto.js';

const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
btn1.addEventListener('click', post)

async function post(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = JSON.stringify({request: _crypto.Encrypt('S', "<Text>")});

    const res = await fetch('http://<IP>:<Port>/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        },
        body: data
    });
console.log(res.body);              //for troubleshooting
console.log(_crypto.Decrypt('C', res.body));    //for troubleshooting
}
```

**Backend**
**server.js**

```
import * as _databaseJS from './database.js';
import * as _crypto from './Crypto.js';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const express = require('express');
const cors=require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 8383;
const corsOptions ={
   origin:'*',
   credentials:true,
   optionSuccessStatus:200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const cryptedRequest = req.body;
    const request = _crypto.Decrypt(cryptedRequest.request);

    let _response="";
    let _output="";
    let _status=0;
    switch (request) {

        case "methode1":
            _output = _databaseJS.GetUser();

            _response = JSON.stringify({
                "reply":_crypto.Encrypt(_output.response)
            });

            _status=_output.status;
        break;

        case "methode2":
            _output = _databaseJS.GetUser();

            _response = JSON.stringify({
                "reply":_crypto.Encrypt(_output.response)
            });

            _status=_output.status;
        break;

        default:
            _response = JSON.stringify({
                "reply": _crypto.Encrypt("Methode not found")
            })

            _status=500;
        break;
      } 


      console.log(_response);

      res.status(_status).send(_response);
});
```

**Crypto.js**

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

function ExecuteInTerminal(query)
{
        const output = execSync(query, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
        return output;
}

function Encrypt(whichOne, message)
{
    const key = new NodeRSA();

    switch (whichOne) {
        case 'C':
            key.importKey(ExecuteInTerminal(`sudo cat /path/to/key/publicRsaKeyClient.key`), 'pkcs8-public-pem');
        break;

        case 'S':
            key.importKey(ExecuteInTerminal(`sudo cat /path/to/key/publicRsaKey.key`), 'pkcs8-public-pem');
        break;
    
        default:
        break;
    }

    const encrypted = key.encrypt(message, 'base64');
    return encrypted;
}

function Decrypt(whichOne, message)
{
    const key = new NodeRSA();

    switch (whichOne) {
        case 'C':
            key.importKey(ExecuteInTermianal(`sudo cat /path/to/key/publicRsaKeyClient.key`), 'pkcs1-pem');
        break;

        case 'S':
            key.importKey(ExecuteInTerminal(`sudo cat /path/to/key/privateRsaKey.key`), 'pkcs1-pem');
        break;
    
        default:
        break;
    }   
    
    const decryptedString = key.decrypt(message, 'utf8');
    return decryptedString;
}

export { Encrypt, Decrypt };
```

First, I tried first to write

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="connection.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="module" src="connection.js"></script>
```

, but in browsers development tools an error occurred. Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".

After that I tried to write

```
<script type="module" src="connection.js"></script>
```

,but even there an error occurred. Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".".

Then I tried instead of "module": "/module", "./module", "../module" and "module/", but I realized that the frontend, no matter what I add to the module, the browser doesn't use the connection.js file. The HTML file only uses the css.

I tried to edit all in the HTML file in the  section. Unfortunately, nothing changes.

Comment: the issue is this line "import { createRequire } from 'module';" and this line "import { createRequire } from 'module';"

It doesn't know where that file is. If you want to import like that without specifying file names you'll need to use a web packer like web pack or browserify etc...

If you know the exact path to the 'module.js' file, you can just give it there. Including the .JS like `import * from './src/scripts/module.js';`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found that I don't need these two lines 
"import { createRequire } from 'module';"
"const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);"
So I replaced all "require" with "import", but it still won't work.